# Searching for a way in bedrock to test for a held item

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm trying to make a named sword in bedrock on the PS4 that, when held, gives regen. I can't find a command that works for detecting when you're holding a certain item. I've tried many and none seem to works with my version. Any help?